How to configure reporting in Cucumber?
I am using Cucumber for automated testing and would like to configure the generation of reports.
What steps do I need to take to integrate reporting with Cucumber?
Are there any examples of Maven or Gradle configuration for this?
Also, if possible, please provide guidance on how to set up automatic report updates with each test run.
I expected that by adding specific plugins or configurations in my Maven or Gradle build files, I would be able to automatically generate reports after each test run.

you might what have a look at
https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting
There is an example there what to put in your maven pom.xml file.
To run it you can use the mvn verify
This will run your tests and then generate a report.
